# MySQL select orderby date returns duplicate values

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb-10.3

I want to get every user and the last payment they do. I got 2 tables here the `users` and `finances`. I tried to add `groupby` and I got the result I want but, it gets the oldest record in the other table. Does anyone know how could I achieve this?

My first query

```
SELECT users.name, users.email, users.phone, users.parent_id, users.section_id, finances.amount, finances.description, schoolyears.name, finances.date 
from users 
JOIN finances on users.id = finances.user_id 
JOIN schoolyears on users.school_id = schoolyears.school_id 
ORDER BY finances.date DESC;
```

Result I got

```
+-----------------+------------------------------+--------------------+-----------+------------+--------+--------------+--------------+------------+
| name            | email                        | phone              | parent_id | section_id | amount | description  | name         | date       |
+-----------------+------------------------------+--------------------+-----------+------------+--------+--------------+--------------+------------+
| Madelynn Stokes | moore.dominic@cartwright.com | +63 (971) 659-8143 |        10 |       NULL | 1000   | New Payables | SY-2019-2020 | 2019-11-14 |
| Annamarie Morar | emile99@hotmail.com          | (0997) 212-7919    |         3 |       NULL | 500    | New Pays     | SY-2019-2020 | 2019-11-14 |
| Madelynn Stokes | moore.dominic@cartwright.com | +63 (971) 659-8143 |        10 |       NULL | 5000   | Old Payables | SY-2019-2020 | 2019-11-13 |
| Annamarie Morar | emile99@hotmail.com          | (0997) 212-7919    |         3 |       NULL | 200    | Old Pays     | SY-2019-2020 | 2019-11-13 |
+-----------------+------------------------------+--------------------+-----------+------------+--------+--------------+--------------+------------+
```

I want only the newest record in other table. the New payables and New pays.

I tried this second query

```
SELECT users.name, users.email, users.phone, users.parent_id, users.section_id, finances.amount, finances.description, schoolyears.name, finances.date 
from users 
JOIN finances on users.id = finances.user_id 
JOIN schoolyears on users.school_id = schoolyears.school_id 
GROUP BY users.id 
ORDER BY finances.date DESC;
```

It works but I got the oldest record.

```
+-----------------+------------------------------+--------------------+-----------+------------+--------+--------------+--------------+------------+
| name            | email                        | phone              | parent_id | section_id | amount | description  | name         | date       |
+-----------------+------------------------------+--------------------+-----------+------------+--------+--------------+--------------+------------+
| Madelynn Stokes | moore.dominic@cartwright.com | +63 (971) 659-8143 |        10 |       NULL | 5000   | Old Payables | SY-2019-2020 | 2019-11-13 |
| Annamarie Morar | emile99@hotmail.com          | (0997) 212-7919    |         3 |       NULL | 200    | Old Pays     | SY-2019-2020 | 2019-11-13 |
+-----------------+------------------------------+--------------------+-----------+------------+--------+--------------+--------------+------------+
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid, it won't execute on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode.) You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: MariaDB 10.3.1,phpMyAdmin 4.9.0.1,PHP 7.3.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=caf315725301d62c8a5e17d86a411e38)**

```
SELECT users.name, users.email, users.phone, users.parent_id, users.section_id, finances.amount, finances.description, schoolyears.name, finances.dateval 
from users 
JOIN finances on users.id = finances.user_id 
JOIN schoolyears on users.school_id = schoolyears.school_id 
where finances.dateval=
(select max(dateval) from finances f where finances.user_id=f.user_id)
```

Comment: You really should test your queries *before* you post them.

Comment: Thanks sir! Can you explain that to me what did you do sir?

Comment: @Vince, there was a syntax error bro :) instead of where I used 'on' :)

Comment: I am trying to convert that into laravel querybuilder but it is hard haha